# Visual C++ Array Literals

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, literals

I am working in windows and I wanted to create my programs through netbeans so I needed to use the linux compiler through cygwin. Until now I have been able to use literal arrays of `int`s like so:

```
int x[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

or in a method

```
methodName({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
```

I recently changed to visual studio but I wasn't allowed to do this. Is there an alternative?

Comment: int x[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; works fine

Comment: What's the declaration of `methodName`? The only way it makes sense is if the argument is `int const (&)[6]` (or a templated version of this), and even then only in C++11.

Comment: @KerrekSB in C++11 one could call a function taking a vector, an std::array, or a lot of things using that syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int x[6] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
```

Such syntax is already supprted by MSVC2010

```
methodName({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6})
```

But this is not supported. And as noted above it would make sense only for "int const (&)[6]" function parameter.

Intead you may use following syntax:

```
methodName(make_array(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

[Example implementation](http://ideone.com/MZ2T6c):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;


template<typename T,unsigned size>
struct Array
{
    typedef T type[size];
    mutable type data;
    Array()
    {
        cout << "Array::Array" << endl;
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        cout << "Array::~Array" << endl;
    }
};

template<typename T> inline
typename Array<T,1>::type &make_array(const T &p1,const Array<T,1> &aux=Array<T,1>())
{
    aux.data[0]=p1;
    return aux.data;
}

template<typename T> inline
typename Array<T,2>::type &make_array(const T &p1,const T &p2,const Array<T,2> &aux=Array<T,2>())
{
    aux.data[0]=p1;
    aux.data[1]=p2;
    return aux.data;
}

template<typename T> inline
typename Array<T,3>::type &make_array(const T &p1,const T &p2,const T &p3,const Array<T,3> &aux=Array<T,3>())
{
    aux.data[0]=p1;
    aux.data[1]=p2;
    aux.data[2]=p3;
    return aux.data;
}

// ...

void test_array(int (&p)[3])
{
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
}

void test_ptr(int *p)
{
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    test_array(make_array(33,22,11));
    test_ptr(make_array(33,22,11));
    return 0;
}
```

Or, [with help of Boost.Preprocessor](http://ideone.com/t42DIm):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

// ______________________________________________________________

template<typename T,unsigned size>
struct Array
{
    typedef T type[size];
    mutable type values;
    Array()
    {
        cout << "Array::Array" << endl;
    }
    ~Array()
    {
        cout << "Array::~Array" << endl;
    }
};

#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/repeat.hpp>

#define MAKE_ARRAY_PP_MAX_ARG_COUNT 16

#define MAKE_ARRAY_PP_PARAM_LIST(z, n, data) const T & BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n)
#define MAKE_ARRAY_PP_PARAM_ASSIGN(z, n, data) aux.values[n] = BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n);

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
template<typename T> inline \
typename Array<T,n>::type &make_array(BOOST_PP_ENUM(n, MAKE_ARRAY_PP_PARAM_LIST, _) , const Array<T,n> &aux=Array<T,n>()) \
{ \
    BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, MAKE_ARRAY_PP_PARAM_ASSIGN, _) \
    return aux.values; \
} \
/**/
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (1, MAKE_ARRAY_PP_MAX_ARG_COUNT)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()

// ______________________________________________________________

void test_array(int (&p)[3])
{
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
}

void test_ptr(int *p)
{
    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    test_array(make_array(33,22,11));
    test_ptr(make_array(33,22,11));
    make_array(33,22,11,00,55,44,66);
    make_array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
    return 0;
}
```